# Force Gradle build to fail when releasing with SNAPSHOT dependencies

Tags: android, gradle

I would like to prevent the usage of SNAPSHOT dependencies when building with Gradle a release version of an Android application or library.
How can I force the Gradle build to fail if there are any SNAPSHOT dependencies when building the release?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use a ResolutionStrategy.

See here for the API:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html

The below example was posted in the Gradle forums by Peter_Niederwieser
https://discuss.gradle.org/t/enforce-no-snapshot-dependencies-in-gradle/3851/2

```
configurations.all {
    if (isRelease) {
      resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
          if (details.requested.version.endsWith("-SNAPSHOT")) {
              throw new GradleException("found snapshot dependency")
          }
      }
   }
}
```

The code must be placed either in the module build.gradle or in the "allprojects" section of the main build.gradle.

Comment: Great! Thanks, it works exactly as expected! Note that the snipped must be in the module configuration.
I also added a condition to check if the application is currently in a release version.

Comment: @bplpu I had to do this to make `isRelease` work: `def isRelease = project.gradle.startParameter.taskNames.any { it.toLowerCase().contains('release') }`

Comment: Question: why do you put the isRelease check *within* the eachDependency block? Doesn't that force iterating through all dependencies every time? Could the if isRelease check be placed outside the complete resulutionStrategy.eachDependency block to say: only for releases do this?

Comment: Yes @Zordid, you are correct. I took the liberty and updated the answer.

Comment: I found a simpler `isRelease` check that seems to work: `configuration.name.startsWith("release")`; that's assuming that the release build type is actually called "release".